# fade in when bg color change

Tags: jquery

I want to change my table row bg color when user hovers, at the same time have a fade in effect. the ff.code doesn't work. any ideas?

```
$(this).fadeIn("slow").css('background-color', '#FFFF99');
```

Comment: is there something wrong with my english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery alone doesn't support this directly. You need to also include the jQueryUI script which adds further animation methods to work with. Then you can use the "animate" function to control further css / class visualisations.

Once you've included jqueryui try the following;

> $(this).mouseenter(function() {
>
> ```
> $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#FFFF99'}, 'slow');
> ```
>
> })
>   .mouseleave(function() {
>
> ```
> $(this)css('background-color','white'); // if default of white etc.
> ```
>
> });

Answer (score 1):

You can use animate() to achieve the effect you want. See [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/75JQ2/1/)

Note, that to use the `slow` on animate you have to include the [jQuery UI plugin](http://jqueryui.com/download)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `fadeIn()` the target needs to have `style.display` set to `'none'` (of course you cannot hover an hidden element, so you'll need to use andyb's suggestion to use `animate()` )